# Collaborative filtering in Python

Tags: python, graphlab

I work now with the [Graphlab](http://graphlab.org/projects/index.html). After installing of this program, I could run the algorithms of Collaborative filtering.
Now I try to work with Graphlab in the Python. I have found already this brilliant [toolkits](http://graphlab.com/products/create/docs/graphlab.toolkits.html#utilities). My question is, does anybody know about [Collaborative Filtering](http://docs.graphlab.org/collaborative_filtering.html) in the python implementation? I couldn't find this tool & it seems me it doesn't implemented for Python...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You question is a bit unclear, what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: For example, I could call pagerank fuction in python implementation (you can find example on the given page). Now, I want use for example ALS in the python implemetation. ALS is one of algorithms from Collaborative Filtering. Anyway I couldn't find this implemetation in the package graphlab for the Python code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the [recommender package](http://graphlab.com/products/create/docs/graphlab.toolkits.recommender.html) in GraphLab Create. It lets you create a collaborative filtering model in just a few lines.

```
import graphlab
sf = graphlab.SFrame.read_csv('my_data.csv')
m = graphlab.recommender.create(data)
recs = m.recommend()
```

You will likely be most interested in the item similarity models, but you should also check out the [other options](http://graphlab.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.recommender.create.html#graphlab.recommender.create) for the `method` argument, such as `matrix_factorization`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from above suggestions in Answer section, I will STRONGLY recommend you to do a course on Coursera [Here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ml-foundations/home/welcome) for getting better understanding of ML and Recommendation Systems. For just getting started with Collaborative filtering, you also may refer this simple and easily understandable blog [Here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/06/quick-guide-build-recommendation-engine-python/) and obvious Turi official [Website](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/graphlab.toolkits.recommender.html) . I hope this helps.